# Create an SQL table drawing columns from another

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL table with the columns (primaryKey,name,age,weight) and I want to generate a new table containing all the data from the original but only the columns (primaryKey,age). Can anyone suggest the SQL command for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CREATE TABLE new_tbl SELECT primary_key,age FROM orig_tbl ;` 
Based on [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table-select.html).

Answer (score 0):

Make a trigger, so when you insert a record, it insert another to the other table: [Here is the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html)  [Here](http://www.roseindia.net/sql/trigger/mysql-trigger-after-insert.shtml) is an example